# How can I make a pointer point to all the elements in an array?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a C code where a pointer can point to all the elements in an array. However, after I dereference the pointer I get the `Segmentation Fault` error.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func_equal(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output)
{
    for (int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        output[i]= input[i]; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t* my_point;
    int32_t someNum[4];

    for (int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        someNum[i]= 2 + (4*i);
    }

    func_equal(someNum, my_point);

    printf("my_point (dereferenced) is %d\n", *(my_point));
    printf("---------\n");

    for (int i= 0 ; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("my_point (dereferenced) is %d\n", *(my_point+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As one can see in my code, I created a pointer called `my_point` and I want to make it point to the array `someNum`. However, when I run the code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) I get the following output:

```
my_point (dereferenced) is 2                                                                                                   
---------                                                                                                                      
Segmentation fault
```

**How can I modify `my_point` to point to ALL the elements in `someNum`?**

Answer (score 2):

I completly lost myself in the presentation of your code. This is by no means a good question and this might not be the correct answer or maybe it is correct but there might be more things wrong....

Why do you do this:

```
YCbCr_MCU[0]= &(color[x].YCbCr_MCU[0]);
YCbCr_MCU[1]= &(color[x].YCbCr_MCU[1]);
YCbCr_MCU[2]= &(color[x].YCbCr_MCU[2]);
```

This looks like your three pointers in the array point to the variables that are ordered in an array. For this just one pointer is enough.

```
uint8_t *YCbCr_MCU =  &(color[x].YCbCr_MCU[0])
```

from this point on you could access all members of just by the pointer  and these conditions would hold:

```
YCbCr_MCU[0] == color[x].YCbCr_MCU[0];
YCbCr_MCU[1] == color[x].YCbCr_MCU[1];
YCbCr_MCU[2] == color[x].YCbCr_MCU[2];
```

This would make it easier to work with the code.

The real problem seems to be here:

```
uint8_t *MCU_Y = YCbCr_MCU[0]; // here YCbCr_MCU[0] is a pointer so this is valid.
....
index = i * (8 * nb_MCU_H)  + j;
R = (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 1.402f + MCU_Y[index]; // look at the MCU_Y here
```

for every index other than `0` this is invalid (okay to be more precise `1` and `2` would be okay to get `color[x].YCbCr_MCU[1];` or `color[x].YCbCr_MCU[1];`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173143/discussion-on-answer-by-kami-kaze-how-can-2-c-programs-produce-identical-numeric).

Comment: @JHBonarius moving two comments to chat is really not warranted. It's a waste of time.

Comment: @JHBonarius you flagged the second last comment, asking they be moved to chat. Which comments? How is it over moderating? Moving comments into a chat is completely harmless.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Sorry for the confusion I flagged the comments (and I just took a random one at the bottom). I did not further specify the point from which on it should be moved (as I did not have one in mind). I do not feel anything of high value is lost, as it seems everything in this QA is in vain anyway.

Comment: @KamiKaze ah yeh, it was you who flagged the comment. I figured it wouldn't hurt to pop them all into a chat. Are you ok with that?

Comment: I would think it is okay, but up to (and including) this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42924397#42924397 I would figure it is still relevant to the answer.